# Is there any way to disable the textfield of a JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I know that `JComboBox` has three components which are textfield, arrow button and the drop down menu.
My task is that disable the textfied so only the button is shown and when clicking the button we can see the dropdown menu.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you please explain it more?

Comment: @MarounMaroun if I understood correctly, he just wants the down-arrow to be present. Upon clicking that, the list appears.

Answer (score 0):

"Dropdown only" is the default behavior. The text field only appears if you set the combo box to be editable.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html